# Define number of classes for image segmentation

Tags: python, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have an error that I don't understand and don't know how to fix on this code shown at https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation:

```
import os

input_dir = "images/"
target_dir = "annotations/trimaps/"
img_size = (160, 160)
num_classes = 3  # <=== CHANGED THIS LINE.
batch_size = 32

input_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(input_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".jpg")
    ]
)
target_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(target_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(target_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".png") and not fname.startswith(".")
    ]
)

print("Number of samples:", len(input_img_paths))

for input_path, target_path in zip(input_img_paths[:10], target_img_paths[:10]):
    print(input_path, "|", target_path)
```

I changed the code as so: `num_classes = 2`.

I know there are similar topics but I don't think the mistake is the same. I am trying to do an image segmentation of the water areas in black and white, so my number of classes should be 2 for the 2 B&W nuances. However it says:

```
Received a label value of 255 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).
Label values: 255 255 [...] 255
```

I think it represents the image in color, so the input and I don't know how to make the code understand that I am referring to the mask.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.